# read LDAP with Java

Tags: java, ldap

I need an efficient way to read all users from LDAP. I have a super/root password in Java

All I need is just to list the names.

All ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a nice code sample [here](https://github.com/yannisf/ldap-java/blob/7bdb6fcb80606b400f96d4c555912f6bc1c8ca8a/src/fraglab/ldap/simple/Main.java):

```
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389/dc=fraglab,dc=net");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=admin,dc=fraglab,dc=net");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "yannis");
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
searchControls.setCountLimit(10);
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> namingEnumeration =
        ctx.search("", "(uid=*)", new Object[]{}, searchControls);
while (namingEnumeration.hasMore()) {
    SearchResult sr = namingEnumeration.next();
    System.out.println("DN: " + sr.getName());
    System.out.println(sr.getAttributes().get("uid"));
    System.out.println("Password:" + new String((byte[]) sr.getAttributes().get("userPassword").get()));
}
ctx.close();
```

It uses the LDAP Naming Service Provider for the
Java Naming and Directory Interface [JNDI](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-ldap.html), and should do what you want with small adaptations (e.g. put the name of you server, at least). The [documentation for the ldap provider](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-ldap.html) is quite good, and will help you extend it to your needs.

Comment: The first link is dead.

Comment: Thanks @kgiannakakis, I updated the link with a github link, hopefully more durable.

Comment: I've copied the sample code inside the post. This is definitely the most durable of all!